# Mac Automator/Applescript(?) to extract URL's from Mail messages

Tags: macos, email, url, applescript, automator

I'm trying to get a text document list of any links in a bunch of email messages that reside in the latest Mac Mail.app (OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite), and am simply stumped.

I thought I'd be able to just...

1. Put a couple of Automator.app actions together in a Service/Workflow,
2. Select/highlight all the email messages within the Mail.app,
3. Select that Service or run that Workflow,
4. And have a text document with every URL/link that could be found within them all.

However, this didn't work.

I figured out how to do this with *one* email message at a time, but that's not what I want. attached is a screenshot of 3 workflows. The first one is the one that works with just one email message & highlighting all the text in it & running the Service. the other two just simply don't work.

I also notice that the the first shows up in the Service Menu with a single email open; once I highlight more than one email message, the option goes away from the Service menu.

Any tips or tricks?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how you could reach your goal, start with creating a new service within Automator (input: "No input", application: "Mail")

The first action is **Get Selected Mail Messages** (Get selected: messages)

The second action is **Execute AppleScript** with the following script:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set mailContentList to {}
    tell application "Mail"
        repeat with selectedMail in input
            set end of mailContentList to content of selectedMail
        end repeat
    end tell
    return mailContentList
end run
```

*This script simply walks through the given messages, reads out the content and passes this list to the next action*

The third action is **Extract URLs from Text**. This is listed as "Extract Data from Text" and one of the types of data is "URLs".

And the final action is **New TextEdit Document**

Save it with a nice name like **Extract URLs from selected mails**
After that the Service is available inside the Services menu inside the Mail app.

In my test I found a few internal URLs without http:// from links to  anchors, so maybe you want to delete all URLs that do not start with **http**. You can do so by using another action *before* creating the new TextEdit document:
**Filter Paragraphs** with options "Paragraphs that start with *http*" (don't know how these parameters are called in English Automator, sorry)

Feel good, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Can confirm it works great! As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37591276/319860), if you want to extract links from the e-mail’s HTML body (rather than visible text) use `source of selectedMail` instead of `body`.

Comment: To filter duplicate urls, add an extra step ‘Run AppleScript’ to the workflow:

`(* Strip duplicates *)
on run {input, parameters}
 set filteredList to {}
 
 repeat with i from 1 to count of items of input
  if item i of input is not in filteredList then
   set filteredList to filteredList & item i of input
  end if
 end repeat
 return filteredList
end run`
(adapted from [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.comp.lang.applescript/xjN6WTs30Jo/RRjmhALokpQJ))