# Mac to extract HTML from Mail messages

Tags: html, macos, email, applescript, automator

I am trying to extract `HTML` from emails using `AppleScript`. I came across this StackExchange post -- [Mac Automator/Applescript(?) to extract URL's from Mail messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378829/mac-automator-applescript-to-extract-urls-from-mail-messages) -- which tries to extract URLs from email content. The extraction code is:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set mailContentList to {}
    tell application "Mail"
        repeat with selectedMail in input
            set end of mailContentList to content of selectedMail
        end repeat
    end tell
    return mailContentList
end run
```

This only extracts the `visible` content, not the entire `HTML` content. I tried adding `with properties {visible:false}` after `content` and then after `input` with no luck from either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the raw source with the `source` property

```
set end of mailContentList to source of selectedMail
```

but you have to extract the HTML portion "manually".